# Tratar retorno do AJAX (responseText)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Fiz um código em AJAX executa o PHP e imprime no HTML o resultado da consulta SQL, o problema é que quando ele exibe na tela, os dados não estão tratados, ficam assim:

[image: Imagem demonstrativa]

O que eu preciso é simplesmente que na tela apareça apenas o conteudo de 'ayzac_episode_name', mas não posso perder as outras informações(principalmente o 'ayzac_episode_id')

seguem os códigos:

AJAX:

```
function searchEpisode(seasonID,divepisodioID) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

var url = "../control/ayzac_control_getEpisode.php?id=" + seasonID;
req.open("Get", url, true);

req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
        var answer = req.responseText;
        alert(answer);
        document.getElementById("episodios" + divepisodioID).innerHTML = answer;

    }
}
```

PHP(função que busca o episódio):

```
    function getSerieEpisodes($seasonID){
    $connect = new ControllerConnect ();
    $objCon = $connect->controllerConnect ();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ayzac_episode WHERE ayzac_season_id = '".$seasonID."'";
    return $objCon->executeSQLFetchObjectEpisodes($sql);
}
```

PHP (executeSQLFetchObjectEpisodes):

```
    function executeSQLFetchObjectEpisodes($sql = NULL) {
    if ($sql != NULL) {
        $query = mysqli_query ( $this->con, $sql );
        while ( $result = mysqli_fetch_object ( $query ) ) {
            $this->rows [] = $result;
        }
        if ($this->rows != null) {
            return $this->rows;
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse retorno que vc recebe, um array, e se vc armazenasse ele em uma variável, $array, e pra ler a informação ayzac_episode_name, vc varresse o array com um foreach, assim:

```
foreach($array->array as $a){
  echo $a->ayzac_episode_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema, de uma forma bem mais simples do que eu imaginei.

Eu percebi que o valor que estava sendo exibido era da função var_dump que estava presente no controlador(que não postei lá em cima)

Estava assim:

```
$objUser = new userMidia ();
$rowEpisode = $objUser->getSerieEpisodes( filter_input ( INPUT_GET, 'id' ) );
var_dump ($rowEpisode);
```

Agora está assim:

```
$objUser = new userMidia ();
$rowEpisode = $objUser->getSerieEpisodes( filter_input ( INPUT_GET, 'id' ) );
$i=0;
echo "<ul>";
while(isset($rowEpisode[$i])){
    echo "<li>";
    echo $rowEpisode[$i]->ayzac_episode_name;
    echo "</li>";
    $i++;
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Obrigado!